# Instalar Sparkling Water versión Nightly Bleeding Edge

Tags: r, rstudio, apache-spark

Estoy intentando instalar Sparklin Water version Nightly Bleeding Edge, la página de H2O, ofrece una sencilla guia de 8 pasos. Pero solo algunos pasos funcionan correctamente. [rsparkling](https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/sparkling-water/master/259_nightly/index.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- El primer problema surge en el paso 2, dicen que hay que instalar `sparklyr` `install.packages("sparklyr")`, pero este te instala una versión vieja la 0.7 y no compatible con la última versión de h2o, lo solucione con `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/sparklyr_0.8.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")`, que instala la version 0.8.4.
- En el paso 3 dicen caragar la libreria sparklyr y utilizar el comando `spark_install(version = "2.3.1")`, para instalar la version 2.3.1 de Spark, tampoco funciona `sparklyr::spark_available_versions() #2.3.0`, pues la última versión disponible es la 2.3.0, lo solucione descargando [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) en su última versión, directamente de la página.
- Estoy atascado en el paso 6, pues no funciona la version instalada `rsparkling` no es copatible con mi version de h2o. `packageVersion("h2o") #'3.21.0.4359'`

Estoy intentando lo siguiente descargue el comprimido de [Sparkling Water 2.3.259_nighty](https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/sparkling-water/master/259_nightly/sparkling-water-2.3.259_nightly.zip), descomprimí el zip, el cual genera una carpeta. Y desde esta carpeta que tengo en descargas utilice el siguiente código.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/USER/Downloads/sparkling-water-2.3.259_nightly/rsparkling.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package 'rsparkling' ...
** package 'rsparkling' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rsparkling)
In R CMD INSTALL
```

Al parecer todo funciona hasta aquí, entonces procedo a realizar los pasos 6 y 7 de la guía.

```
# 6 Set Sparkling Water version to be used with RSparkling
options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = "2.3.259_nightly")
library(rsparkling)
# 7. Connect to Spark
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local")
Error: invalid version specification ‘2.3.259_nightly’
```

> Error: invalid version specification ‘2.3.259_nightly’

Ahí es cuando surge el error, siguiendo la guía paso a paso, al parecer se esta instalando una versión vieja de `rsparkling`, es lo mismo que si hiciera `install.package("rsparkling")` instala la versión 0.2.4 y mp ña 2.3.259_nighty.

**Nota:** Mi version de `h2o Nightly Bleeding Edge` y `rsparkling #0.8.4`, funcionan correctamente por separado. Lo mismo que el paquete `SparkR`.

La última versión de h2o, puede ser instalada con: el siguiente comando.

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/4365/h2o-3.21.0.4365.zip")

# Finally, let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

**Spark 2.3.1**

```
system('spark-submit --version')
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_151
Branch 
Compiled by user vanzin on 2018-06-01T20:37:04Z
```

Como puedo solucionar este problema gracias.